# Semantics of __imp_ symbols

Tags: windows, dll, linker, reverse-engineering, portable-executable

Calling DLL functions involves the linker generating a stub, *unless* the function was declared `__declspec(dllimport)` in which case the stub can be bypassed in favor of an indirect call straight to the import table which is slightly more efficient, e.g.

```
__declspec(dllimport) void ExitProcess(int);
ExitProcess(0);
```

generates

```
call qword ptr [__imp_ExitProcess]
```

where `__imp_ExitProcess` resolves to a location in the import table in the executable.

I'm trying to figure out exactly how `__imp_ExitProcess` is resolved. It occurs as a symbol in kernel32.lib to be sure, but that symbol has storage class `IMAGE_SYM_CLASS_EXTERNAL`, section number zero and value zero, which amounts to just saying 'this will be defined somewhere else' without actually ever defining it.

Does the `__imp_` prefix have special meaning, i.e. does the linker notice that prefix and take it as an instruction to resolve the symbol to the import table entry for the DLL function whose name has that prefix removed? Or is something else going on?

Comment: Which `kernel32.lib` are you looking at?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky The 64-bit version that ships with Microsoft C++ 2013. 286522 bytes.

Comment: It is an external and is defined somewhere else, in kernel32.dll.  This is resolved at runtime by the loader.  The prefix has no significance.

Comment: @HansPassant Right, the loader at run time works from the import table and doesn't care about the prefix. But at link time, how does the linker know `__imp_ExitProcess` is supposed to point to the import table instead of being rejected as an undefined symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Members of `kernel32.lib` are not normal object files but special placeholders. From the [PE/COFF spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx):

> Traditional import libraries, that is, libraries that describe the
>   exports from one image for use by another, typically follow the layout
>   described in section 7, “Archive (Library) File Format.” The primary
>   difference is that import library members contain pseudo-object files
>   instead of real ones, in which each member includes the section
>   contributions that are required to build the import tables that are
>   described in section 6.4, “The .idata Section.” The linker generates
>   this archive while building the exporting application.
>
> The section contributions for an import can be inferred from a small set of information. The linker can either generate the complete,
>   verbose information into the import library for each member at the
>   time of the library’s creation or write only the canonical information
>   to the library and let the application that later uses it generate the
>   necessary data on the fly.
>
> [...] a short import library is written as follows:
>
> ```
>   Archive member header   
>   Import header
>   Null-terminated import name string
>   Null-terminated DLL name string
> ```
>
> This is sufficient information to accurately reconstruct the entire contents of the member at the time of its use.

In `kernel32.lib` on my machine, `__imp_ExitProcess` is mentioned in the first and second linker members (symbol list) and point to the specific pseudo-object describing the import:

```
Archive member name at 8: /               
50107C36 time/date Thu Jul 26 01:07:34 2012
         uid
         gid
       0 mode
   106CA size
correct header end

    2515 public symbols

    [...]

    3C874 ExitProcess
    3C874 __imp_ExitProcess

    [...]

Archive member name at 3C874: KERNEL32.dll/   
50107639 time/date Thu Jul 26 00:42:01 2012
         uid
         gid
       0 mode
      2D size
correct header end

  Version      : 0
  Machine      : 8664 (x64)
  TimeDateStamp: 50107639 Thu Jul 26 00:42:01 2012
  SizeOfData   : 00000019
  DLL name     : KERNEL32.dll
  Symbol name  : ExitProcess
  Type         : code
  Name type    : name
  Hint         : 371
  Name         : ExitProcess
```

So, as you can see, the data in .lib explicitly says that it refers to an import name `ExitProcess` from the DLL `KERNEL32.dll`. The linker can use this to build necessary metadata in the import section.

Now, the above only discussed how the `__imp_ExitProcess` symbol is resolved. I'm not 100% sure but I think if a symbol (e.g. `ExitProcess`) has been resolved to such an import stub, and it *does not* start with `__imp_`, then the linker has to generate a jump stub (for code symbols), or an indirect access (for data accesses) to the IAT slot.

Comment: What you say in your second last paragraph is true, and my understanding of stub generation also concurs with yours in your last paragraph. I'm still not clear however on how `__imp_ExitProcess` is resolved. To be sure, the coincidence of numbers in the symbol lists gives a hint that it is related to `ExitProcess` in some way, but how does that translate into a specification or algorithm for resolving the symbol? My first conjecture was that it works by stripping the prepended `__imp_`...

Comment: One might also conjecture from looking at the symbol lists that it might work something along the lines of 'When an extern symbol has the same symbol list number as an explicit import and they are the only two symbols with that number, take them as being connected in this way,' but I've no idea whether that's the case or whether it's something else - if it is that, what happens if there are several symbols with the same number? Is it the first linker member that's definitive? Even though the spec says that one is obsolete? Etc.

Comment: @rwallace: read the PE/COFF spec, especially the part about the first and second members of an archive (symbol indexes). You use the index to find the archive member which defines the symbol. In this case the archive member is not a full object file but an import stub, so you don't need to do any additional symbol lookup - just use the info from it to generate import directory metadata.

Comment: Yeah, I've read that section ten or fifteen times now, though I might be still missing some implications. But you reckon the algorithm is some version of my second suggestion above? Maybe you're right, though I also now have a data point, which I'll post in an answer.

Comment: I don't know why you're worrying about whether there are additional symbols pointing to the same member or not. Worry about the one you actually need. 1) take the symbol you need to resolve (`__imp_ExitProcess`). 2) Look it up in the index (first or second, should not matter). 3) extract the target archive member. 4a) if it's a full COFF, do the full link step. 4b) if it's an import stub (pseudo-object), get the target DLL name and the import name/ordinal and generate the import directory data. 5b) replace the reference to the `__imp_` symbol with the address of the newly generated IAT entry.

Answer (score 5):

The linker adds to your program a function like:

```
void (*__imp_ExitProcess)(int) = ...;

void ExitProcess(int n)
{
    return (*__imp_ExitProcess)(n);
}
```

where __imp_ExitProcess points to the "real" ExitProcess in KERNEL32.DLL.

Declaring this in your code:

```
__declspec(dllimport) void ExitProcess(int);
```

is equivalent to:

```
extern void (*__imp_ExitProcess)(int);

#define ExitProcess (*__imp_ExitProcess)
```

except that __declspec(dllimport) is handled by the compiler, not by the preprocessor.

Answer (score 3):

Just came up with a test that gives a data point. The following program:

```
__declspec(dllimport) void ExitProcess(int);

void __imp_ExitProcess(int x) {
}

int main() {
    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

crashes when compiled with the Microsoft compiler and run (but runs okay if the empty function is renamed to anything else); thus, it seems the linker behaves as though the `__imp_` name is special, at least in the sense that a linker that behaves that way will generate a correct executable in all cases where the Microsoft linker does so, unless I'm missing something.